# Python openpyxl conditional format containsText

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I all.

I have this code.
I need to add conditional format at the cells, the code working with numbers, but not with texts.
With texts or haven't effect or generate errors on file open

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import formatting, styles
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule, Rule
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle



df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
"Status": ['SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'FAIL'],
"Value": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\emarmis\\OneDrive - Ericsson AB\\WORK\\DEV\\PYTHON\\Ferie\\test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, 'TEST', startrow=1, startcol=1)

wb  = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['TEST']

red_color = 'ff0000'
yellow_color = 'ffff00'
red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=red_color, end_color=red_color, fill_type='solid')
yellow_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=yellow_color, end_color=yellow_color, fill_type='solid')

# This not working
rule = Rule(type='containsText', operator='containsText', text='"FAIL"')
#rule = Rule(type='containsText', operator='containsText', text='FAIL') # same problem with or without double quote on text
rule.dfx = DifferentialStyle(fill=red_fill)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('D3:D7', rule)

# This generate error at the file open
#ws.conditional_formatting.add('D3:D7', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='containsText', formula=['FAIL'], fill=red_fill))

ws.conditional_formatting.add('E3:E7', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['20'], fill=red_fill))
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E3:E7', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='greaterThan', formula=['25'], fill=yellow_fill))


wb.close()
writer.save()
```

This is the result of the code above

[image]

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this helps but it worked for me. Thou i cant get additional conditions to work.
String 'c-tur' gets red text with a another red fill:

```
red_text = Font(color="9C0006")
red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE")
dxf_c = DifferentialStyle(font=red_text, fill=red_fill)
rule_c = Rule(type="containsText", operator="containsText", text="c-tur", dxf=dxf_c)
rule_c.formula = ['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("c-tur",B2)))']
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B2:'+column_name+str(antal_kolumn), rule_c)
```